# Is it possible to create coded animated wallpapers?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, desktop, gdi

The idea is to ultimately have a program that runs in the background. This program paints pixels to the desktop wallpaper at a rate of at least 24 pixels per second.

I've already tried using certain dekstop [handles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548578/1883288) but that does not have the desired result. This solution paints over cursor and icons as well.

Suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683791/drawing-on-the-desktop-background-as-wallpaper-replacement-windows-c

Comment: I don't know how hapy the os would be about you overriding their drawing. Maybe there might be something useful in Windows.h though

Comment: This used to be easily possible, using the [Active Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Desktop) feature, that shipped up to and including Windows XP. Starting with Windows Vista, there is no published interface to render the desktop background anymore. Another option was to use the [Hardware Overlay Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797814.aspx). By setting the desktop color to a unique color, you could use color keying to render to the desktop only (leaving all pixels intact that do not happen to be the key color). That, too, is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

This rust crate can change the wallpaper of many OS:
https://docs.rs/wallpaper/2.0.1/wallpaper/

It may not yield the performance you where talking about, in my experience it can change the background a few times per second.